# How to import python package from current directory?

Tags: python, import, module, package, distutils

If I have a python package:

```
  foo.py
  setup.py
  mypackage/
```

How can I import `foo.py` from `setup.py` without colliding with a preinstalled package `foo`? I want to make sure that:

`import foo`

will import the `foo.py` in current directory and not a different package named `foo`.

Is there something like "import from current dir?"

Comment: There are `__init__.py` files missing for those directories to be a Python package.

Comment: Have you tried `from . import foo`? That's a relative import that will import the foo module in setup.

Comment: @Evert: that won't work if it's not inside a package. i want to import ``foo.py`` from ``setup.py`` so the package is not installed

Comment: Your "outer" directory indicates it is also a package; provided it is indeed a package, `from . import foo` will import the foo.py that is at the same level as setup.py.

Comment: my outer directory has no __init__.py and it's not a package, it's just the directory that contains the package. setup.py is not supposed to be part of the package is it?

Comment: I also think that Python will first import a package in the current directory (when using a normal import such as `import foo`), before it tries packages elsewhere. I.e., your cwd comes first in `sys.path`.

Comment: I don't know whether you want `setup.py` to be inside a package; it's not impossible. But your naming confused me.

Comment: @Evert: my naming is the standard: mypackage for directory of the package "mypackage" with "mypackage/mypackage" containing the py source

Comment: To extend upon my other comment, here's what the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path) say: As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list, path[0], is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter". So yes, you can just use `import foo` and the `foo.py` next to `setup.py` will be imported; any other `foo` package is later in `sys.path`, and thus will not be imported.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of removing the outer directory name. It doesn't really add anything, except some confusion.

Comment: You can refer to this definitive python import guide https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html